# Suggested feature for GIT to store marked changes in a special location (like a stash) (is is already there?)

Tags: git

While testing a feature I have just coded up, I will place in some code that I want to make sure **NEVER** gets committed. I have never forgotten to remove this code, but I'd feel much better if there was some tag that could be placed in the code that would prevent GIT from accepting the code.

I will usually put in a comment like: `// FOR TESTING ONLY, DO NOT SUBMIT`. That way even if I do somehow let it through it will be caught in review.

Plus, a problem with this is that I usually push my code at the end of the day, but I have to stash this.

Is there anyway to automate this?

Comment: Could you consider using a pre-commit git hook to check for that line and reject the commit if it includes it?

Comment: I was wondering if git hooks existed. That would work, and would work to solve some other issues we have. We have a file that created by a tool that we don't want in the repo, and we can't use gitignore on it.
I'll google it and see how it works.
Thanks!